# What happens when database shut down before triggers executed?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Assume I have table in PostgreSQL as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  userid integer,
  productid integer,
  description citext,
  price numeric
)
```

and some triggers on it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER afterinsert
  AFTER INSERT
  ON A
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE DoSomething1();

CREATE TRIGGER beforeinsert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON A
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE DoSomething2();
```

Now, if I do this:

```
Insert into A values (1,3,'some description',100.5)
```

What will happen is:

1. `beforeinsert` run `DoSomething2()`
2. the row is inserted to `A`
3. `afterinsert` run `DoSomething1()`

My question is what happens if between 2 and 3 the database shuts down?
when it starts again... what will hapen? will it roll back both the inserted row and roll back `beforeinsert` trigger?

Basically I just don't understand what is considered the Atomic operation in this case. is it the Insert + triggers or just the row?

Comment: It should do those operations in transaction. When recovering engine will look for uncommited transactions and should rollback them. But I am not sure. It should be like that.

Comment: As far as I know the engine does not roll back committed transaction so question is when the insert row is committed? when `2` is done or when `3` is done?

Comment: It should commit after all are done, I believe. Try to rollback from third trigger and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The triggers are part of the transaction, and it won't commit until they've finished running. If the database shuts down before the transaction commits, it'll be rolled back. The rollback affects all changes that were made in the transaction, including the changes made by the triggers.

Comment: What if DoSomething2() does some insert & updates and invoke more triggers? Basically you are saying that this whole "giant" thing is just one transaction with one commit?

Comment: Yep, all changes initiated within a transaction are part of the transaction.  Some databases can also do [autonomous transactions](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Autonomous_transaction), where a procedure invoked within one transaction can make changes in a separate transaction that's independent of the original.  But PostgreSQL doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a soft shutdown (that is, tell the database to shutdown: pg_ctl -m fast), it will rollback all open transactions. This includes all changes made by any trigger so far.

If you kill the database (like a kill -9), the database has no chance to properly commit or rollback everything. Next time you start the database, it will run a recovery and rollback all the changes to the point of the last successful commit.

All triggers are part of the ongoing transactions, all changes are only committed once all AFTER triggers finish.